# Updating Shortest Path Weight from One Destination to Another

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph with possibly negative edge weights. Given a destination $t$. Suppose that we have already known $d_v$, the shortest path weight from $v$ to $t$. If I'd like to compute the shortest path weight from $v$ to another destination $t'$ instead (call it $d'_v$), how to use $d_v$ to calculate $d'_v$ in $O(mlog(n))$ where $m=|E|$ and $n=|V|$?

Comment: "Suppose we already known $d_{v'}$, ...". Do you mean $d_v$?

Comment: Yes. It's a comma after $d_v$.

Comment: Are the following the known conditions? "$G=(V,E, w)$ is a directed graph where $w$ might be negative. $t, v, v'$ are three fixed vertices in $V$.  We know  the weight of shortest path from $v$ to $t$."

Comment: Yes. Say these conditions are given.